# Welcome message on Master Page after login

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, master-pages

I have a message name to be showed on MasterPage when the user is logged in. Right now it is showing just **MyAccount**. Please see the code and let me know how to achieve that.
Tried but couldn't managed in the master page. Please see my code as ref:-

```
<div id="nav-right">
  <div class="showhide-account">
     <img src="images/user.png" width="13" height="13" alt="">&nbsp;&nbsp;My Account
  </div>
  <div class="nav-divider">|</div>
  <div id="logout">
          <a href="Login.aspx" id="logOut" runat="server">Logout</a>
   </div>
   <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you want to show in place of "My Account" after login? I think, you want to show "UserName" or something else

Comment: @Piyush: Yes I want to show username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:- 
There are two way to do so:-

1st Way:-

I think you have to add lblusername lable in your div.

```
<div class="showhide-account">
    <img src="images/user.png" width="13" height="13" alt="">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Label ID="lblUserName" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
```

Then, set the Text of lblUserName in code behind

```
lblUserName.Text = Session["UserName"].ToString();
```

2nd Way:- 
 Added Property

```
public string UserName
        {
            get
            {
                //return the object from session
                return (string)Session["UserName"];
            }

            set
            {
                Session["UserName"] = value;
            }
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //set UserName with UserName from Database value after username &
           //password verification 
           this.UserName = "XYZ User";
        }
```

and then in .aspx page,

```
<div class="showhide-account">
     <img src="images/user.png" width="13" height="13" 
                          alt="">&nbsp;&nbsp;<%=UserName%>
  </div>
```

Comment: I tried like this <div class="showhide-account">
                                <img src="images/user.png" width="13" height="13" alt="">'<%#Session["username"].ToString() %>'<asp:Label ID="lblWelcomeMessage" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                            </div>

but not working

Comment: See modified answer!!

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. getting this error

Comment: You have to set lblUserName.Text on Page_Load event

Comment: Yes, setting there only.Still getting the same error

Comment: You have two label under your div, lblUserName and lblWelcomeMessage?

Answer (score 0):

If your are using membership you can put `<%= Membership.GetUser().UserName %>` whenever you want current username appear. For example like:

```
<div id="nav-right">
    <div class="showhide-account">
        <img src="images/user.png" width="13" height="13" alt="">&nbsp;&nbsp;My Account - <%= Membership.GetUser().UserName %>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-divider">|</div>
    <div id="logout"><a href="Login.aspx" id="logOut" runat="server">Logout</a></div>
    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```